# how to access fragments elements in MainActivity()?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment

In my project, I want to set visibility of fragments buttons from MainActivity. But the problem is, it gives NullPointerException(). I also maked listBtn & gridBtn as static. I used below code :

```
 FirstFragment fragment = (FirstFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.    <frameLayout Id>);

  main_page_fragment.listBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  main_page_fragment.gridBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to your fragment view from Activity class because activity uses its own view (ex: R.layout.activity_main). Rather you can set visibility in your corresponding fragment class which will do the same job.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
        Button listBtn = (Button)view.findviewById(R.id.listBrn);
        Button gridBtn = (Button)view.findviewById(R.id.gridBrn);
        listBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        gridBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment `onCreateView` callback is called after `onCreate` method of activity, so i think you have tried to get access from it. That views will be accessible only after `onResumeFragments` callback is called, you should perform your actions with fragments there.

Another tip is that you strongly should not call views of fragments **directly** like you did or via **static reference to views** that's [**the worst**](http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html). You should avoid such dependencies on fragments inner implementation. Instead of it, better is create some method like `setInitialState` (the name depends on your business logic) and just call it from activity.

So result code: 
In activity:

```
private FirstFragment fragment;

protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //init fragment here
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    fragment.setInitialState();
}
```

In fragment:

```
//this will be called on fragment #onResume step, so views will be ready here.
public void setInitialState() {
   listBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   gridBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add your fragments dynamically from MainActivity like so:

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, YOUR_TAG)
            .commit();
```

Then you can define method in your fragment like so:

```
public void hideButtons()
{
    yourBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

And call it from activity:

```
fragment.hideButtons();
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with this for several hours and I found a much simpler solution.

Inside the fragment, simply make a public function (outside the on create view method) with the behavior that you want.

```
fun hideElement() {
    binding.button.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

And then in main activity access to the fragment and call the function.

```
binding.bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
when (it.itemId){

      R.id.someFragment -> someFragment.hideElement()
           
        }
    }
```